# Wordpress Still Requesting Old Url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url, redirect

I have a wordpress site which is working on local. In order to test the mobile design I changed the URL from settings to my local IP. It worked fine, and then I changed it back to localhost. But problem is accured today, my local IP is changed and now wordpress still redirecting me to my old url.

My local IP is 192.168.1.40 now

I changed site url from database manually and still have problem.

[image: Fiddler investigate]

Comment: How did you change the URL? The only way that I would trust to ever change a site's domain is by using the [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) with the [command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) `wp search-replace "http://olddomain.example.com" "http://256.256.256.256" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run`, removing the last parameter when you actually want to run it. If you only changed it in settings, that very rarely does what you expect it to.

Comment: I only changed it from settings.

Comment: Maybe this is a question better suited to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ???

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your data, you can edit `site_url` and `home` rows in the `wp_options` table.

[image]

Comment: I changed it already. Unfortuanetly I still have the problem.